# How can I configure removing space between line comment slasles and text in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

If I want to comment line I use "Ctrl+/" and get the "//" at start of line

[image]

Then I use auto formatting with "Ctrl+alt+L" keys and get

[image]

At the end I must remove space between "//" and text manually every time...

[image: enter code here]

Can I do all of these steps in one time? I didn't find any settings for this...

Comment: which version, 12 or 13 ?

Comment: I use 13 CE but it's doesn't matter. In 12 I had the same problem.

Comment: Would like a full solution in typescript for this

Answer (score 8):

An alternative, not perfect though, is:

1. Editor -> Code Style -> Java -> Code Generation
2. Uncheck `Line Comment at first column`

The menu hierarchy is the one in Intellij IDEA 14.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you can use a setting to avoid the further indentation of your comment (the effect of the second screenshot).

Your comments will look like this:

```
//        Bundle b = new Bundle();
```

That might not be quite exactly what you want, but at least you will be able to use "Ctrl+/" after the reformatting to return the line to a properly aligned state.

Here is the setting:

1. Go to Settings -> Project Settings -> Code Style -> Java
2. On the `Wrapping and Braces` tab,  find the tree item at the top: `Keep when reformatting` and tick: `Comment at first column`

Answer (score 0):

This works for Scala.

Preferences -> Editor -> Code Style -> Scala -> Other -> Comment Code

Uncheck `Line comment at first column` and `Block comment at first column`.

---

Example:

```scala
def regexTest(): Unit = {
    Comment
```

When press comment shortcut in line 2, the above code becomes

```scala
def regexTest(): Unit = {
    //Comment
```

Version 2020.2